# identityserver4 issuer having 2 different value

Tags: hostname, apigee

I am getting 2 different issuer in the token when i hit the same url of my app service.
I have apigee and the backend azure app service with the runtime stack netcore2.1 Identityserver is integrated with default issueruri. we never overrides issueruri.

App service have the custom domain like xxxx.local.com and apigiee have the url like dev1-xxxx.com. The token endpoint dev1-xxxx.com/token which will generate the access/security token from idservice.

with the above config we are getting the indeterminate issuer in the generated token. one time dev1-xxxx.com (this is the apigiee url) and another time xxxx.local.com (this is the app service custom domain). what could be the issue in our code?

in the appinsights log i can see the some requests are logged as apigee url one ore more request are logged with direct url (app service)